# How is throw undefined, proper use of $.extend()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following fiddle: [basic js class](http://jsfiddle.net/v4xXt/1/) and when I try either `throw 'error'` or the commented out line in the code example, `throw AS.Exception.message('Test Error message')` the console comes back saying that its undefined (it being throw). and I am all like ..... No it's not - Unless I am using it wrong.

Also - the other issue is that `AS.Class` is using the [`$.extend()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) which *Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.* so I should be able to do something like:

```
throw self.message // var self = this;
```

But if I try it states that message doesn't exist or isn't a function and if the `$.extend()` merges two objects, it should, the method `message`, be in the same scope. thus I shouldn’t have to do `AS.Exception.message` - since its been merged into this new object ...

Ideas?

Comment: I get "uncaught exception: error" in the Firebug console in FF 26, so looks like the `throw` statement is fine. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have is a bunch of object literals. It's not a "class". When you do `var self = this` it executes in the global scope and `self` just holds a reference to the global object (which of course will not have a `message` property).

> the console comes back saying that its undefined (it being throw)

`throw` cannot be undefined (it cannot be defined either for that matter). It is a language construct, not a reference. I think what you mean is that you are throwing the value `undefined`. The reason for that is the function you call does not return anything (so it implicitly returns `undefined`). What you effectively have is this:

```
AS.Class = $.extend(AS.Exception, {
    throwError: function(){
        throw undefined;
    }
});
```

Comment: that didnt answer my extend message but gives me insight into throw.

Comment: @user3217071 - The first bit answers your `extend` question. `self` is a reference to the global object, not to your `AS` object.

Comment: Oh sorry I read failed to notice that. So how do I use the AS.Exception.message() in side of the AS.Class with out having to do AS.Exception.message - or is the way I am doing it the proper way?

Comment: @user3217071 - You can do `throw this.message()` since `this` will refer to the correct object within that function. `self` doesn't work because when you assign `this` to `self` it refers to the global object.

Answer (score 0):

The `.message()` method returns `undefined`. And that is what is thrown.

http://jsfiddle.net/v4xXt/1/